# Copying values from a numpy array to balance the dataset

Tags: python, numpy, dataset

I have a dataset where one of the similar looking class is imbalanced. It is a number dataset where class labels go from 1 to 10.

Grouping by label (`y`) on the training set gives the following output:

```
(array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10], dtype=uint8), array([13861, 10585,  8497,  7458,  6882,  5727,  5595,  5045,  4659,
    4948]))
```

As could be seen `1` has `13861` data-points and `7` has only `5595` data-points.

To avoid the class imbalance between `1` and `7` I want to put some extra images for `7` class.

Here is `train` set:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat

train = loadmat('train.mat')

extra = loadmat('extra.mat')
```

Both `train` and `extra` are dictionaries with 2 keys `X` and `y` each.

Here is the shape of `train` and `extra`:

```
train['X'] --> (32, 32, 3, 73257)
# 73257 images of 32x32x3
train['y'] --> (73257,1)
# 73257 labels of corresponding images

extra['X'] --> (32, 32, 3, 531131)
# 531131 images of 32x32x3
extra['y'] --> (531131, 1)
# 531131 labels of corresponding images
```

Now, I want to update `train` dataset with labels from `extra`, primarily taking `x%` of data with label `7` in `extra` into `train`. How could I do this?

I tried the following:

```
arr, _ = np.where(extra['y'] == 7)
c = np.concatenate(X_train, extra['X'][arr])
```

But I get an error saying `IndexError: index 32 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 32`

Comment: Can you provie a sample of `train.mat` and `extra.mat` ?

Comment: @b-fg It is a dictionary containg `X` and `y` as keys. `X` and `y` are numpy arrays.

Comment: @b-fg Have also added an example on what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example on  just numpy arrays that easily translates to your case. As you have edited, use `numpy.where` to find the labels you want on `extra['y']` and keep these indices. These are then used together with `numpy.append` to concatenate (last axis for `X` and first axis for `y`) your original dataset with the extra one.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)

# First find the indices of your y_extra with label 7
x_extra = np.random.rand(32, 32, 3, 10)
y_extra = np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(10,1))
indices = np.where(y_extra==7)[0] # indices [3,4] are 7 with seed=100

# Now use this indices to concatenate them in the original datase
np.random.seed(101)
x_original = np.random.rand(32, 32, 3, 10)
y_original = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(10,1))

print(x_original.shape, x_extra[..., indices].shape) # (32, 32, 3, 10) (32, 32, 3, 2)
print(y_original.shape, y_extra[indices].shape) # (10, 1) (2, 1)

x_final = np.append(x_original, x_extra[..., indices], axis=-1)
y_final = np.append(y_original, y_extra[indices], axis=0)

print(x_final.shape, y_final.shape) # (32, 32, 3, 12) (12, 1)
```

Comment: Like you used `-1` to specify last axis. How could I concatenate an array of shape `(73257, 32, 32, 3)` and `(35102, 32, 32, 3)`?

Comment: specifying `axis=0`

Comment: What does `...` mean in `x_extra[..., indices]`?